# Scheduled task spills into the next period

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I have a task in Windows 10 Task Scheduler that runs every hour.  The task is running a Java JAR, and it's actually taking longer than an hour.  Task Scheduler is terminating the task run when it reaches an hour and starting the next run.  Is it possible to not terminate any existing runs when starting a run?

Answer (score 0):

Under the Settings tab for the task, you can select the behavior if the task is already running. You can set this to "run a new instance in parallel", like this:

[image: Run new instance in paralel]